# Plane line showing instead of Dotted line in xml android

Tags: android, xml, dotted-line

I am trying to show dotted line "---" on my view. I have searched many examples on stackoverflow and using similar drawable code and calling on my view as well. On my IDE it is showing Dotted Line but when i am running it on my device it is showing plane straight line. Please suggest me in this regard why it is happening.

My Drawable dotted.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <stroke
        android:dashGap="3dp"
        android:dashWidth="2dp"
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/black" />
</shape>
```

My View where i am calling it.

```
 <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dotted_line"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your **View** is not working then try to use **ImageView** it's working

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/dotted_line"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layerType="software" />
```

Comment: thats alot it works. Don't know the logic why it was not working with View but for this it worked.

Comment: I am also struggling this issue but can't find